# Bookmarks of individual longtable rows?

Tags: hyperref, longtable, bookmarks

I'm in possession of a lengthy table, individual sections of which are reachable from within the document via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301590/latex-hyperref-to-individual-longtable-rows) workaround.

However, I want to get them to show up as bookmarks and don't know how. The hyperref package has this option-

```
linktoc=none,section,page,all    % defines which part of an entry in the table of contents is made into a link
```

I thought of putting something like

```
\section*{}[First Part]
\label{firstpart}
\input{./firstpart}
```

But that gives errors, probably because sectioning commands don't work inside tables or something. 
There's also the `\listof{}{}` command, but it works with figures, tables, lists and I'm not sure how to use it properly.

minimal working thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{
        amsmath,
        amsfonts,
        amssymb,
        mathtools,
        gensymb,
        microtype,
        float,
        graphicx,
        color,
        multirow,
        rotating,
        booktabs,
        mathtext,
        longtable,
        units,
        geometry,
        fullpage,
        multicol,
        }
    \usepackage[font=small, labelfont=sc]{caption}
    \usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=3]{hyperref}
    % hyperref to individual longtable rows
    \newcounter{ltrow}
    \newcommand{\rowlabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{ltrow} \label{#1}}
% 
% 
%     
\begin{filecontents}{firstpart.tex}
& & & & & & foo \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{secondpart.tex}
& & & & & & bar \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{thirdpart.tex}
& & & & & & foobar \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
& & & & & &  \\ 
\end{filecontents}
% 
% 
% 
\begin{document}
%
\begin{center}
\footnotesize   
\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont
\hrule
\selectcolormodel{gray}
\rowcolors{2}{yellow}{white}
%   
\begin{longtable}{r| l l l l l | p{9cm}}
\caption{foo} \\
foo & foo & foo & foo & foo & foo & foo \\ \hline \hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
%
\rowlabel{row:firstpart}
\input{firstpart} 
\rowlabel{row:secondpart}
\input{secondpart} 
\rowlabel{row:thirdpart}
\input{thirdpart} 
\end{longtable}
\label{tbl:try2}
foo is at \ref{row:firstpart} \\
bar is at \ref{row:secondpart} \\
foobar is at \ref{row:thirdpart} \\
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show a document with your code, not only fragments. A `\label` after `\section*` is pretty useless! Which errors are reported?

Comment: `\protect\section` might help!

Answer (score 1):

With `\protect\section` everything seems alright`. If a link is needed, more has to be done, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=3]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{filecontents}{firstpart.tex}
\blindtext[3]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{longtable}{p{8cm}ll}
  \protect\section{Foo}\label{foo} & Foo & Stuff  \tabularnewline
  \input{firstpart} \tabularnewline
  \protect\section{Foobar}\label{foobar} & Foobar & Important stuff  \tabularnewline
  \input{firstpart} \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

In \ref{foo} we have seen important stuff!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, I don't recommend this at all!

Comment: Removing all of the packages that gave errors of any sort and using the above example yielded
tex:62 Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \protect \section
tex:62 Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \protect \section
tex:62 Missing \endgroup inserted \protect \section{Foo}
tex:62 Missing } inserted \protect \section{Foo}
tex:62 Missing } inserted \protect \section{Foo}
tex:62 Missing } inserted \protect \section{Foo}
tex:62 Missing \cr inserted \protect \section{Foo}
tex:62 Missing { inserted \protect \section{Foo}
... and like this for lots more rows

Comment: I gave `\section` as an example for something which appears in the toc and automatically gets bookmarked.

Comment: @vlg: As long as you don't provide real code I won't change my answer. I showed you a way how it works

Answer (score 0):

Inserting `\pdfbookmark{<bookmark-name>}{<label-name>}` before each row, I managed to get the respective .pdf bookmarks to them. They work as intended, only if the command is put in the right place (or else it doesn't appear in correct order) along with the correct label. I can't get the level=0 or 1 option to work, but all good things in due time, I guess.
Likely there exists a more elaborate way to the same end, but for now this works.